# Como remover o nome das classes do executável sem perder o dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++, rtti

Meu objetivo é apenas remover o nome das classes do executável, mas ainda continuar com a habilidade de usar `dynamic_cast`. O problema é que se o RTTI for removido, e assim o nome das classes, não existe nenhum substituto para o `dynamic_cast`.

Já tentei construir um sistema alternativo ao RTTI guardando as informações das classes em uma variável estática, mas eu não sei como converter os ponteiros corretamente, principalmente quando enfrento o "problema do diamante". E ainda por cima, poderia dar algum  problema em libs que uso (SDL, GLFW, etc) .

O compilador que uso é o Min-GW, e nem mesmo o `-s` ou `strip` remove esse tipo de dado.

Estou desesperado procurando alguma maneira de fazer isso, nem que seja substituindo diretamente o nome das classes no .exe gerado por strings vazias.

Answer (score 0):

Não existe forma estabelecida de fazê-lo no Min-GW, pois você quer usar uma função da linguagem removendo as premissas nas quais ela se baseia.

`dynamic_cast` requer RTTI, que embute nome das classes no executável.

Processos posteriores de ofuscação ou compiladores alternativos com esta preocupação *talvez* existam, mas neste caso já se está fora do escopo da linguagem C++.